# CSS3 input focus problems

Tags: html, forms, input, css

I have a form with some inputs. What I want is that when user clicks on the text box it highlights with a color. To do this I'm using CSS3 and the CSS3 Generator in Chrome and Firefox 3.6.17. But I'm not getting results in any browser. Here's the code I'm using.

```
.user-input:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #249663;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #249663;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #249663;
  behavior: url(../css/pie.htc);
}
```

Any help?

Best Regards,
Tiago Castro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add outline none to your :focus...

```
.user-input:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

You might need to force webkit to get rid of its default styles...

```
.user-input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```